# local variable dependency on the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, hashicorp

I am trying to create target group attachment to the instances. e.g.
if there are 3 target groups and 2 instances, would like to attach 3 target groups to the 2 instances.

Here is my code

**instances**

```
resource "aws_instance" "web_servers" {
  ami                         = "ami-1234"
  instance_type               = "t3a.small"
  subnet_id                   = module.vpc.private_subnets[0]
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.keypair.key_name
  count                       = 2
  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "gp3"
    volume_size           = var.ws_storage
    encrypted             = true
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  tags = merge(
    { Name = "${var.project}-${var.env}-ws-${count.index}" },
    var.tags
  )
}
```

**Target group attachment local variable**

```
locals {
  tg_attachments = distinct(flatten([
    for tg in var.lb : [
      for instance in aws_instance.web_servers : {
        tg_name = tg.tg_name
        tg_port = tg.listener_port
        tg_protocol = tg.protocol
        tg_instance = instance.id
      }
    ]
  ]))
}
```

**target group attachment**

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ws_tg_attachement" {
  depends_on = [
    time_sleep.wait_30_seconds,
    aws_lb_listener.listener,
    aws_instance.web_servers,
    aws_lb_target_group.tg
  ]
  for_each = { for entry in local.tg_attachments: "${entry.tg_name}-${entry.tg_port}-${entry.tg_instance}" => entry }
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.tg["${each.value.tg_name}-${each.value.tg_port}"].arn
  target_id        = each.value.tg_instance
  port             = each.value.tg_port
}
```

**ERROR**

```
for_each = { for entry in local.tg_attachments: "${entry.tg_name}-${entry.tg_port}-${entry.tg_instance}" => entry }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.tg_attachments is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many
│ instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the for_each
│ depends on.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest, you can't create resources based on list or maps with unknown arguments at `plan` time. In your case:

```
 tg_instance = instance.id
```

will only be known **after** `apply` (not before), and that's why TF errors out. You either have to refactor your code to have all values known at plan time (change `instance.id` with something that you know at plan time), or use `-target` to **create instances first**:

1. First create instances only:

```
terraform apply -target aws_instance.web_servers
```

2. then create the rest of your resources:

```
terraform apply
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, but I need a way around to make it work this, without using -terget. Or is it possible to use count in place of the second nested loop

Comment: @naeem Sadly its not possible, as long as you have `instance.id` in your local.

Answer (score 0):

Your local value result is a wholly-unknown list because you've used the `distinct` function. In order to decide the result of that function Terraform must compare all of the values in the list, which includes comparing the instance ids. Because the instance IDs aren't known yet, Terraform also cannot predict the result of the `distinct` function.

However, if you use the instance *index* instead of the instance *ID* then Terraform will always know that value during planning, because instance IDs are a Terraform concept rather than a remote API concept:

```
locals {
  tg_attachments = distinct(flatten([
    for tg in var.lb : [
      for instance_idx, instance in aws_instance.web_servers : {
        tg_name         = tg.tg_name
        tg_port         = tg.listener_port
        tg_protocol     = tg.protocol
        tg_instance_idx = instance_idx
      }
    ]
  ]))
}
```

The index of a list element is the "key" of that element, so you can use the two-symbol form of `for` as shown above to get an `instance_idx` for each element. That'll set `tg_instance_idx` to `0`, `1`, `2`... depending on the `count` value for `aws_instance.web_servers`. Those index values will always be known during the planning phase, because Terraform always knows the `count` value for a resource during planning.

This means that when you set `target_id` you will then need to finally cross-reference with the original resource to get the actual instance ID, like this:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ws_tg_attachement" {
  for_each = { for entry in local.tg_attachments: "${entry.tg_name}-${entry.tg_port}-${entry.tg_instance_idx}" => entry }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.tg["${each.value.tg_name}-${each.value.tg_port}"].arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.web_servers[each.value.tg_instance_idx].id
  port             = each.value.tg_port
}
```

Comment: Perfect I really like the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue writing the code as follows.

**Targert Group attachment**

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ws_tg_attachement" {
  
  for_each = {
    for pair in setproduct(range(length(var.lb)), range(var.web_server.count)) : "${pair[0]} ${pair[1]}" => {
      target_group_arn = "${var.lb[pair[0]].tg_name}-${var.lb[pair[0]].listener_port}"
      port = var.lb[pair[0]].listener_port
      target_id = pair[1]
    }
  }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.tg[each.value.target_group_arn].arn
  target_id = aws_instance.web_servers[each.value.target_id].id
  
  port             = each.value.port
}
```

**lb variable**

```
lb = [
    {
        tg_name = "SSH"
        listener_port = 22
        protocol = "HTTP"
        cidr = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    },
    {
        tg_name = "nginx"
        listener_port = 80
        protocol = "HTTP"
        cidr = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
]
```

**web_server variable**

```
web_server = {
    name = "web"
    ami = "ami-09d3b3274b6c5d4aa"
    type = "t2.micro"
    storage = "20"
    count = 2
}
```